# Update document library folder columns in sharepoint code

Tags: document-library, folder, updatelistitems

How to update document library folder columns in sharepoint C# code?
I want to update Test column folder properties.

```
SPFolder newItem = item.Folder.SubFolders.Add(title);
newItem.Update();
newItem.Item["Test"] = testVar;
newItem.Item.Update();
```

Comment: Does your code not work? What is the result?

Comment: It doesn't update the column.. But no exception too...

Comment: Are you sure the folder that is added is of a content type that has a column called "Test"? Btw, the `newItem.Update();` line is not required.

Comment: Test is list content type. Not folder type.. I just created a column called "Test" manually and tried to update.

Comment: The code works fine for me either with newItem.Update() or without. Still, you don't need newItem.Update();